# queryset based on related model

Tags: django, django-views

I've got two models. One (FAQ) is related to the other (FAQCategory). I'm trying to develop a queryset of FAQCategories that are assigned to FAQs, but only if at least one of the FAQs has both the question and answer filled in.

```
class FAQCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)       

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class FAQ(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(FAQCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
```

For example, we have 3 FAQCategories

1) General
2) Shipping
3) Warrenty

1) General is not assigned to any faqs. It should not show up in the queryset

2) Shipping is assigned to a FAQ instance, but that FAQ doesn't have an answer on it. Shipping should not show up in the queryset

3) Warrenty is assigned to a FAQ. That FAQ has both an answer and a question value. As a result, Warrenty should appear in the queryset.

How would I write this in django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply,

```
from django.db.models import Q

exclude_expression = Q(faq__isnull=True) | Q(faq__question__exact="") | Q(faq__answer__exact="")
qs = FAQCategory.objects.exclude(exclude_expression)
```

**References:**

- [Complex lookups with **`Q`** objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)
- [**`isnull`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull)
- [**`exact`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-exact)

Comment: probably all of them should be `is_null`

Comment: Nop... Since question ans answer fields are CharField, in DB those values are stored as empty string.

Comment: That is incorrect Arakkal. A charfield can be None. I've just proven this through my testing.

Comment: I see... Which Database are you using?